# How do I save terminal output to a file?

Tags: command-line

How do I save the output of a command to a file?

Is there a way without using any software? I would like to know how.

Answer (score 1718, accepted):

Yes it is possible, just redirect the output (AKA [`stdout`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin))) to a file:

```
SomeCommand > SomeFile.txt
```

Or if you want to append data:

```
SomeCommand >> SomeFile.txt
```

If you want [`stderr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) as well use this:

```
SomeCommand &> SomeFile.txt
```

or this to append:

```
SomeCommand &>> SomeFile.txt
```

if you want to have both [`stderr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) and output *displayed on the console **and** in a file* use this:

```
SomeCommand 2>&1 | tee SomeFile.txt
```

(If you want the output only, drop the `2` above)

Comment: Note that `someCommand 2> someFile.txt` and `someCommand 2>> someFile.txt` also redirects `stterr` to someFile.txt

Comment: I'm trying to do this with gcc command but it doesn't work. It works with other commands, but not this one. It simply creates the output file with nothing inside it.

Comment: @Nik-Lz Often this is because the command is sending all its output on stderr. If gcc is generating error messages, this seems likely. See Slothworks comment for how to capture stderr instead of stdout.

Comment: NB: to get the output of the `make` command into a file it requires this syntax instead: `make > someFile.txt 2>&1` (source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/redirecting-make-output-to-file-594997/#post2938625)

Comment: I have a problem that it stops writing when the file reaches about 8MB. Is this a known limit?

Comment: @relG Please specify exactly which method you are using above. The whole command would be better.

Comment: @Seth: SomeCommand > output.txt

Comment: what if your text is a copy paste into the terminal and it's a bunch of formatted code?

Comment: @Urasquirrel I don’t understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Seth, is there a faster way to do the same?

Comment: @kalpajagrawalla Faster way to do what?

Comment: redirecting output to a file (I have a C++ program, whose output (10^5 lines of strings, each in a new line), I wish to redirect to a file, but using the above solutions, my laptop hangs.

Comment: @kalpajagrawalla Sounds like a hardware limitation. You're asking your machine to write 100,000 lines at once, while your app is doing its thing. I'd try just waiting it out.

Comment: &>> is giving error

Comment: Thank you very much! I finally understood the difference between > and >> :-)

Answer (score 1580):

To write the output of a command to a file, there are basically 10 commonly used ways.

#### Overview:

> <sub>*Please note that the `n.e.` in the syntax column means "not existing".*
>
>   There is a way, but it's too complicated to fit into the column. You can find a helpful link in the List section about it.</sub>

```
          || visible in terminal ||   visible in file   || existing
  Syntax  ||  StdOut  |  StdErr  ||  StdOut  |  StdErr  ||   file   
==========++==========+==========++==========+==========++===========
    >     ||    no    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    || overwrite
    >>    ||    no    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
   2>     ||   yes    |    no    ||    no    |   yes    || overwrite
   2>>    ||   yes    |    no    ||    no    |   yes    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
   &>     ||    no    |    no    ||   yes    |   yes    || overwrite
   &>>    ||    no    |    no    ||   yes    |   yes    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
 | tee    ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    || overwrite
 | tee -a ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |    no    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
 n.e. (*) ||   yes    |   yes    ||    no    |   yes    || overwrite
 n.e. (*) ||   yes    |   yes    ||    no    |   yes    ||  append
          ||          |          ||          |          ||
|& tee    ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |   yes    || overwrite
|& tee -a ||   yes    |   yes    ||   yes    |   yes    ||  append
```

#### List:

- `command > output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command >> output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.
- `command 2> output.txt`

  The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command 2>> output.txt`

  The standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, it will not be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.
- `command &> output.txt`

  Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command &>> output.txt`

  Both the standard output and standard error stream will be redirected to the file only, nothing will be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file..
- `command | tee output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command | tee -a output.txt`

  The standard output stream will be copied to the file, it will still be visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.
- **(*)**

  Bash has no shorthand syntax that allows piping only StdErr to a second command, which would be needed here in combination with `tee` again to complete the table. If you really need something like that, please look at ["How to pipe stderr, and not stdout?" on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2342826/4464570) for some ways how this can be done e.g. by swapping streams or using process substitution.
- `command |& tee output.txt`

  Both the standard output and standard error streams will be copied to the file while still being visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, it gets overwritten.
- `command |& tee -a output.txt`

  Both the standard output and standard error streams will be copied to the file while still being visible in the terminal. If the file already exists, the new data will get appended to the end of the file.

Comment: Thanks for the table, it's excellent! This should be top answer

Comment: Great information! Can you also add the details of 2>&1 / 1>&2 / 3>&1 ?

Comment: @karthick87 This is not really related to the question about redirecting output to a file, because it just redirects one stream to another. `2>&1` redirects STDERR to STDOUT, `1>&2` redirects STDOUT to STDERR and `3>&1` would redirect stream 3 to STDERR.

Comment: Just a note that '|&' wasn't working for me on macOS. This is due to it having an older version of bash (I think). The less elegant '2>&1 |' works fine though

Comment: `|&` did not work for me on GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). `2>&1 | tee` produced the desired output of StdOut and StdErr to given file.

Comment: @samkhan13 `|&` should be included in Bash since version 4.0 as synonym for `2>&1 |`. I believe you either mistyped something in the command, have another Bash version than you claim, or tested it in a different shell, like `sh` instead of Bash. Are you really sure?

Comment: @ByteCommander I get the error: `sh: 1: Syntax error: "&" unexpected` when I use `|& tee` from a Python script in a c9.io server. It seems a different shell is being used. `echo $SHELL` shows `/bin/bash` and `$SHELL --version` shows version 4.3.11(1)-release. I tried `#!/bin/bash` in my python script but I still get `sh: 1: Syntax error`. I got what I needed so I'm giving up on sorting the weirdness between `sh` and `bash` on my server. Thanks.

Comment: @samkhan13 looks like you are running `sh` and not `bash` (or maybe `bash` in `sh` mode...). You can check what exactly your current shell process is using `ps -p $$ -o cmd=`, because `echo $SHELL` is unreliable and will show you your login shell, ignoring whether you might have started a different subshell.

Comment: Also `&>>` does not work with bash(I'm on Mac), so I had to change it to `>> log.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @Caner It definitely works with modern Bash versions, like 4.3.48 as it is currently used by Ubuntu 16.04, and can be found in the [official documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Appending-Standard-Output-and-Standard-Error). Your Mac probably has an older version of Bash which doesn't have this feature yet, but note that this site is only about Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: what about n,y,y,y ?

Comment: @user1133275 That is quite complicated, but you can do something like `{ YOUR_COMMAND | tee -a FILE.TXT ;} 2>&1 1>/dev/null | tee -a FILE.TXT` - this first copies stdout and appends it to your file, then redirects stderr to stdout and disacrds the old stdout, then again copies and appends the new stdout (the redirected stderr) and appends it to your file too. This approach will probably mess up the line order of the two streams though... not sure. Try it out.

Comment: What is the meaning of `&` at `|& tee` ?

Comment: @Jas to redirect both stderr (2) and stdout (1) streams.

Comment: Is `&>` the same thing as `>&`?

Comment: @ProQ Not sure, but seems like it. Didn't think that would work too.

Comment: Does this apply to `make` output redirection too?

Comment: @Danijel All applications that write to the terminal have to use the same StdOut and StdErr streams (unless maybe some very rare and specific exceptions), so you can use the same redirection mechanisms. For `make` it surely works as well. Btw, you could also just have tried it...

Comment: @ByteCommander There was a note somewhere that triggered me to ask: "if you use `make` do it like this: `make > file.txt 2>&1` ".

Comment: In a modern Bash, `&> file` is a shorthand for `> file 2>&1` @Danijel . Your version is still correct as well though, and recommended if you need to support other or older shells.

Comment: For those Mac users with old bash versions, run `brew upgrade bash` to get to the most recent version. (Trust me, it's worth the time)

Comment: `&>` works for me to redirect all outputs to different place instead of terminal.

Comment: You should add `2>&1` option in your table **`;)`**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and what about with nohup. can we add nohup and  & on the head and end directly?

Comment: n.e. (*) is simple: `2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)`. (Don't forget the space.) By the way, thanks for `|&` --didn't know about that one.

Comment: I think better way is `command 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt` rather than `\&`

Comment: syntax error near unexpected token `>' while using &>>

Comment: You could also add `2> | tee file.txt` to only have StdOut without StdErr on both terminal and file.

Answer (score 138):

You can also use `tee` to send the output to a file:

```
command | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

A slight modification will catch stderr as well:

```
command 2>&1 | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

or slightly shorter and less complicated:

```
command |& tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

`tee` is useful if you want to be able to **capture command output while also viewing it live**.

Comment: It says that the & is unexpected, and doesn't write the log at the same time as the command runs. I am using this in a bash file however, does that make any difference?

Comment: @tim687 I have removed that edit.  Sorry about that...wasn't a part of my original answer.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! tee will append the file in real time, right? I have a backup script that I use to,lol , backup my pc, but the logging is not in real time. My pc goes to sleep after the backup is finished, and the log file is empty. Should I use another command to log the commands?

Comment: how do I interpret meaning of `2>&1`?

Comment: @Mahesha999 2 is the file descriptor for STDERR, and 1 is for STDOUT.  So that 2>&1 sends STDERR to STDOUT.  This SO question explains it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean

Comment: Instead of `2>&1 |`, one can also simply use `|&`.

Comment: This approach nicely handles commands with prompts. Thank you very much!

Comment: @tim687 You're probably not using Bash, or you're using a super old version of Bash.

Comment: on ubuntu 20.04 , I have a problem with `2>&1`  . when I use it , I can't capture the java exceptions on the console . But with `|&` and tee , all is captured in the file

Comment: The `|& tee` does not work live for me. I only get the output to the terminal only after execution completes.

Answer (score 24):

## The `script` command

There are two different questions here. The first is in the title:

> How do I save terminal output to a file?

The second question is in the body:

> How do I save the output of a command to a file?

All the answers posted here address the second question but none address the first question which has a great answer in **Unix & Linux**:

- [Save all the terminal output to a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/200642/200094)

This answer uses a little known command called `script` which saves all your shell's output to a text file until you type `exit`. The command output still appears on your screen but **also appears in the text file**.

The process is simple. Use:

```
$ script ~/outputfile.txt
Script started, file is /home/rick/outputfile.txt
$ command1
$ command2
$ command3
$ exit
exit
Script done, file is /home/rick/outputfile.txt
```

Then look at your recorded output of commands 1, 2 & 3 with:

```
cat ~/outputfile.txt
```

This is similar to [earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/485762/307523) of:

```
command |& tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

- But you don't have to use `|& tee ~/outputfile.txt` after each `commnd`.
- The `script` command has added benefit (or disadvantage) of reloading `~/.bashrc` when it starts.
- The `script` command shows the command prompt (`$PS1`) followed by the command(s) you entered.
- The `script` command records all the details in full color.

## Send output to clipboard

Many times we want the output to go to the clipboard so we can paste it later. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5130969/6929343) you can use:

```bsh
cat ~/.bashrc | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in almost any application to paste the terminal output into your document. To paste the terminal output in the clipboard back into your terminal use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead.

Comment: +1 :-) I use `script` in the following context: [Wake me up when a slow command line process wants my attention?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1106774/wake-me-up-when-a-slow-command-line-process-wants-my-attention/1106780#1106780)

Comment: @sudodus +1 on your linked answer there. I would never have dreamed of using `script` for such an application :)

Comment: This looks promising but didn't work for me with Cygwin. `Script started on 2021-08-20 11:14:49+10:00 [TERM="xterm" TTY="/dev/cons0" COLUMNS="80" LINES="24"]` *(script is empty)* `Script done on 2021-08-20 11:14:49+10:00 [COMMAND_EXIT_CODE="0"]`

Comment: script is the solution you need when you have enter interactive responses y/n etc

Comment: @Greg This is a Ubuntu site. Your problem is with `Cygwin` which is used to run Linux on Windows. To run it in Ubuntu you would have to use wine. So you would be using [Linux to Cygwin to Windows to Wine to  Linux](https://askubuntu.com/a/110540/307523) for your problem to be supported here on **Ask Ubuntu**. Otherwise it would be a problem best posted on **Super User**.

Answer (score 23):

You can redirect the command output to a file:

```
your_command >/path/to/file
```

To append the command output to a file instead of overwriting it, use:

```
your_command >>/path/to/file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! is there any Limits ? like the max size of the file ?

Comment: The max file size is just limited through the file system

Comment: This answer will not save stderr. Use &> , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637827/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-in-a-bash-script and http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Comment: The OP never asked to save stderr

Comment: It says "No such file or directory". Is it possible to also create the directories automatically?

Answer (score 22):

An enhancement to consider -

Various scripts will inject color codes into the output which you may not want cluttering up your log file.

To fix this, you can use the program [sed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/sed.1.html) to strip out those codes.  Example:

```
command 2>&1 | sed -r 's/'$(echo -e "\033")'\[[0-9]{1,2}(;([0-9]{1,2})?)?[mK]//g' | tee ~/outputfile.txt
```

Comment: How to save the output in a way that colours are conserved ?
I would like to import the result of a command in libreoffice and keep the colours.

Comment: @madrang: I only read your comment now but you may find this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/502456/32239) useful.

Comment: Oh, almost exactly what I am looking for. How to print also on screen the output?

Comment: Note that many commands that produce colorized output, such as `ls` and `grep`, support `--color=auto`, which outputs color codes only if standard output is a terminal.

Answer (score 15):

`some_command | tee command.log` and `some_command > command.log` have the issue that they do not save the command output to the `command.log` file in real-time.

To avoid that issue and save the command output in real-time, you may append `unbuffer`, which comes with the `expect` package.

---

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
unbuffer some_command | tee command.log
unbuffer some_command > command.log
```

Assuming `log.py` contains:

```
import time
print('testing')
time.sleep(100) # sleeping for 100 seconds
```

you can run `unbuffer python log.py | tee command.log` or `unbuffer python log.py > command.log`

More information: [How can I save a command output to a file in real-time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/453485/16704)

Comment: They do save the output as they receive it, the problem is that python turns on buffering when the output is not to a TTY. Other options for disabling this in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/q/107705/2072269

Comment: Thanks!  Spent so long looking for this, and this is exactly what I needed.  Works with the stdout from the Google Assistant scripts.

Comment: You don't need to install expect, stdbuf does the same thing and is generally already there in your distribution. You can "line buffer", which still has the advantage of some buffering and saves time, or completely "unbuffer".

Answer (score 11):

For `cron` jobs etc you want to avoid the Bash extensions.  The equivalent POSIX `sh` redirection operators are

```
Bash          POSIX
------------  --------------
foo &> bar    foo >bar 2>&1
foo &>> bar   foo >>bar 2>&1
foo |& bar    foo 2>&1 | bar
```

You'll notice that the POSIX facility is in some sense simpler and more straightforward.  The `&>` syntax was borrowed from `csh` which should already convince you that it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to output to the file while the command is being run:

```
script -c ./path/to/executable.bash -f log.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

## Use terminal emulator features

An option not mentioned yet, that can save colours / colors too, is to use a console program — such as `Konsole` (KDE/Plasma's default terminal emulator) — to save the output.

### Konsole

```
Konsole has: 
File > Save output as...
```

the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>; it allows the output to be **saved as a text file, or as HTML including colors!** I'm not sure exactly how much it will save but in my test it only included ~1000, the entire terminal scrollback, (you can increase the buffer by creating a new profile, Profile > New..., and then change the Scrolling settings to capture more; Konsole version 4:21.08.1).

### gnome-terminal

`gnome-terminal` has "copy output as HTML" too, which allows pasting the HTML into a document; it preserves colour but only copies the content of the output currently shown on screen AFAICT.

#### generically

You can, of course, do a straight drag-select (hold left mouse button whilst dragging) and then copy (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, Edit > Copy, or right-mouse-click and choose copy).

##### others?

Feel free to modify this answer to include other popular terminal apps. My favourite, `Yakuake`, does not appear to have this feature nor did most of the popular terminals I reviewed, including terminal.app and Hyper.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.bashrc` (based on the `script` command):

```
### Logging function:
start_terminal_logging()
{   
    if [ -z "$SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE" ]; then    
        # Log each session to a separate file:
        logdir=~/.terminal_logs
        logfile=$logdir/session_log_$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)_$$.txt        
        # If no folder exist make one:
        if [ ! -d $logdir ]; then
            mkdir -p $logdir
        fi
        export SCRIPT_LOG_FILE_ACTIVE=$logfile
        # Start logging, a=append, q=quiet:
        script -aq $logfile
        exit
    fi
}
### Start logging:
start_terminal_logging
```

This will give you a separate file for each session:

```
session_log_20240107_152455_1955.txt
session_log_20240124_112455_2971.txt
session_log_20240125_092455_6925.txt
session_log_20240125_092750_7048.txt
session_log_20240125_092808_7079.txt
.
.
.
```

Filename contains a timestamp, so you can easier find what you are looking for.