# Logging script output to a file

Tags: bash, scripts, log, logging, output

I wrote a simple script to monitor my gpu clocks and temps. I wanted it to, aside from being visible on the terminal, log its output on an external file. How could I achieve this? My script below, for reference:

```
#!/bin/bash

watch -n 1 "amdconfig --odgc" "amdconfig --odgt"
```

The question is not a duplicate because I'm using the "watch" command.

Comment: @usmanayubsh I had also voted to close but I was wrong, it's not a duplicate. The OP is using `watch` and that makes things more complicated.

Comment: Ok @terdon, I was also having second thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't want to do that. `watch` is designed to be, um, *watched*. Its output is formatted in such a way as to make redirecting it impractical. While you can actually do it using something like `tee`, the output will be many blank lines and very little useful information.

So, in the specific case of `watch`, you're better off writing your own little script that does the same thing:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
## This is an infinite loop, the script will run until you kill it
while :; do
  ## Run the command whose output you want to monitor
  amdconfig --odgc" "amdconfig --odgt

  ## Wait for 2 seconds. This mimics what the watch command does
  ## and also avoids spamming your cpu. 
  sleep 2
done
```

Save that script as `~/bin/amdwatch` or whatever you like, make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/amdwatch`) and then redirect its output to a file:

```
~/bin/amdwatch > amdwatch.log
```

That will run the script until you stop it manually and execute the `amdwatch` command every two seconds, saving its output to `amdwatch.log`.

For most scripts, what you are looking for is `script.sh > outputFile.txt` or `script.sh >> outputFile.txt`. See [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/420981/85695).

Answer (score 2):

`watch` will by default clear the screen each time it prints to `stdout`. So I would suggest you use a `while loop` with a delay. Then you could use `script`  command or `tee` to log the output. For instance,

```
while [ 1 ]; do df ; sleep 0.25; done | tee -a MY_FILE
```

It both will be displayed on the screen and will go to file, appending each run of the command