# How to record the output of a bash script from terminal without suppressing the terminal output?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

How to record the output of a bash script from terminal without suppressing the terminal output like `$ ./bash-script.sh >> terminal.txt` ? and I want to record the resulting output to text and keep it in the terminal as well.

Comment: It simply writes *any* output into a file. The language is irrelevant, not sure what you mean?

Comment: In what way? it is an exact dupe, what requirements?

Comment: The alleged duplicate asks `How do I save the output of a command to a file?`  This question asks `I want to record the resulting output to text and keep it in the terminal as well.` While the linked post provides partial answer, this is not exact duplicate, hence reopening this question

Comment: @Serg Common Serg, Why? Let's not do this. You know there are many other candidates, it is a dupe anyway and the dupe fully addressed his issue. Nothing wrong with posting a dupe.

Comment: @user72216 I am sure it's a dupe, but not of the one that was linked.   I did find a different one. Will close it shortly

Comment: I think this kind of functionality cannot happen by design since that would eat up disk space like sweet cookies.  What looks possible to me is to use some Log feature implemented in the commands that have it available.

Comment: @userDepth, The last log is important, if the terminal is set to record last 3 days log only of it's operations, will that hurt?

Comment: @PavelSayekat That should be done by ROOT uknow. And root should change it's password regularly or other alternative for security hardening. Three days may trump using snapshots but would take more space. am I right ?

Comment: Though the question is not exactly the same but the answers  has my solution here https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file/731237#731237. It took long for me to get which one is the exact.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `tee` command is good for capturing output from non-interactive commands. For interactive terminal applications, the package `bsdutils` gives you `script` command that allows recording the output to terminal while allowing you to interact with the application like usual. The difference between the two is that `script` will give the application the impression of running under a terminal and this might make a difference how the utility behaves. Also, `script` captures standard error without requiring to do additional redirects in the shell command line.

You can use it like this:

```
$ script -c script.sh output.log
```

(where `script.sh` is assumed to be found in `$PATH`) or

```
$ script -c "script.sh arguments" output.log
```

Running it without `-c "${command}"` option will run shell and allows saving the shell session to a file.

As `bsdutils` is an "essential" package and its priority is "required" you might have it already installed. Just try issuing command `script` (followed by `exit` to stop recording to the default file `typescript`).

In general I personally usually prefer `script`  over `tee` though many interactive terminal applications seem to run just fine when output is piped to `tee`.

Comment: @PavelSayekat as far as I know, that package comes with Ubuntu by default, so you should already have `script` command installed.   The name of the package is exactly that - `bsdutils`. My `apt-cache search bsdutils` finds it alright, so maybe you did a typo or something , but it's definitely there , and it's part of `main` repository

Comment: `script` is a very useful tool, particularly in combination with `ansifilter` or the like. Just be careful when using it with tools like tmux or GNU screen. In those cases, start script first and don't do anything fancy with the multiplexer.

Comment: @Serg yep, I have noticed that too, it is preinstalled in my system, but the typo was from the answer poster :)

Comment: @FooF when I run like  `$ script -c test.sh output.log`, the command does not recognizes my test.sh script, but the test.sh script runs good on its own when I run it, :)

Comment: @PavelSayekat   This is because `test.sh` is probably not located in any of the directories listed in `$PATH` variable. `-c` will accept any command that is located in  any directories listed in `$PATH`. To run script that is in your current directory, you need to either do `script -c ./test.sh output.log` or ` script -c "bash test.sh" output.log` . Possible other issue is that you did not make script executable , so use `chmod +x test.sh`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Yep `script -c "bash test.sh" output.log` worked.

Answer (score 10):

> I want to record the resulting output to text and keep it in the terminal as well

What you want is `tee` command. It allows echoing text to `stdout` and to a file. For example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/passwd | tee output_file.txt                                      
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2989 6月  17 20:45 /etc/passwd
$ cat output_file.txt                                                          
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2989 6月  17 20:45 /etc/passwd
```

Comment: The requirement of the question were changing and it seems I was late to adjust the answer according to the last change. congrats! :)

Comment: @Anwar indeed , I reviewed the edit history just now. OP clearly kept changing it.  Perhaps they didn't phrase it properly right away.

Comment: Sorry Anwar, i knew the previous hacks, so I thought everyone will answer excluding those hacks, my bad, no one is a mind reader. but thanks for your concern.

Comment: @PavelSayekat no problem. That's ok :)

Comment: If you want to capture `stderr` output as well make that `some_command |& tee output_file.txt`. I think `|&` is a csh-ism, but it works in modern bash and is easier than the `2>&1` thing.

Comment: It's the same thing. ` If ‘|&’ is used, command1’s standard error, in addition to its standard output, is connected to command2’s standard input through the pipe; it is shorthand for 2>&1 |` ( https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html )  Also , `&>`  .  But 2>&1 is portable, can be used in zsh and ksh, others are bash specific

Comment: @Serg that solution makes total sense but somehow it is not working for me, so untill I sort it out........, you know what I mean :)

Comment: @PavelSayekat  Can you explain what exactly is not working ? Are there any errors ?  Use paste.ubuntu.com  if you want to show any output, just copy text there and provide link here in comments

Comment: @TorKlingberg yes, |& and 2>&1 both works for scripts also to capture logs to file.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `tee`

For example,

```
./script.sh | tee logfile
```

will cause the output of the script to be saved in `logfile` as well as shown in the terminal output.

If you want to store all outputs of subsequent script executions, you may want to *append* to that file. In that case, you'd use `tee -a` instead

```
./script.sh | tee -a logfile
./script2.sh | tee -a logfile
```