# file descriptor in unix

Tags: bash, scripts

i have the below shell script:

```
pankaj@pankaj-Lenovo-G500:~$ cat demoscr
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
   echo "Error : Number are not supplied" 1>&2
   echo "Usage : $0 number1 number2" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
ans=`expr $1 + $2`
echo "Sum is $ans"
```

when i run the shell script, error message is being printed but nothing is present in the er1 file. why?

```
pankaj@pankaj-Lenovo-G500:~$ ./demoscr > er1
Error : Number are not supplied
Usage : ./demoscr number1 number2
pankaj@pankaj-Lenovo-G500:~$ cat er1
pankaj@pankaj-Lenovo-G500:~$ cat er1
```

Answer (score 2):

The simple `>` operator redirects STDOUT to a file. However, your script is printing to STDERR (see the `1>&2` at the end of your `echo` commands). That's why you see the text in the terminal and not in the log file.

You need to redirect the output of the script using `2>` (redirect STDERR only) or `&>` (redirect both STDOUT and STDERR) instead.

See [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file/731237#731237) for more details about output redirection to files in Bash.