# Can I save the output of ifconfig -a to a file?

Tags: command-line, networking, server

Apparently I had problems with the lxd service, so I restarted the service

```
Service lxd restart
```

And now if it shows the network adapter, but is no longer called eth0, now has a similiar name to: "dbr0" but because of screen problems I cannot see the full name of the adapter.

My question is: can I send the output of the command

```
ifconfig -a
```

to a file so I can read it later with a file editor like nano or mc?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can. This is called redirection. Here's an example.
`$ ifconfig -a > read.later`

The above command will place the output of `ifconfig -a` into a file called read.later which you can open with the text editor of your choice or display to the screen with commands like `more read.later` or `less read.later` or even dare I say it `cat read.later`

For further detail on redirection, see [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)