# Command output to file with dynamic file name

Tags: command-line

I found [this helpful post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) on how to export command output to a file, e.g.

```
command > myfile.txt
```

But is there a way I can export to `myfileXXX.txt`, where `XXX` is the day of the week, e.g. `Mon`, `Tue`, `Wed`, etc., or even `1`, `2`, `3`, etc., or is there something similar like calendar date of month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=$(date '+%d%m%Y %H%M%S')
DAY=$(date +"%u")
c=$DAY$dt
command > myfile"$c".txt
```

or this command:

```
command > myfile$(date +%a).txt
```

Comment: To get only the dayname, `command > myfile$(date +%a).txt` is sufficient.