# How to run commands in the shell in parallel without disrupting the output?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have the following shell script:

```
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 0.1 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 0.2 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 0.5 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 1 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 25 0.1 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 25 0.2 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 25 0.5 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 25 1 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 2 0 10 0.1 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 2 0 10 0.2 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 2 0 10 0.5 &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 2 0 10 1
```

And my main function has a structure like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc<18)
    {
        cout<<"Insufficient parameters"<<endl;
        cout<<"loop #ofGen popSize chrLen Pc PmNumerator randPopRate BOAimmigrantsRate Pn algoType #ofBOAsamples mkpfileNo noiseType prb env per sev"<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    int algoType;// GA or PBIL
    int mkpfile;
    loop = atoi(argv[1]);
    GA.generation = atoi(argv[2]);
    GA.popSize = atoi(argv[3]);
    GA.chromosomeLength = atoi(argv[4]);
    GA.Pc = atof(argv[5]);
    GA.PmNumerator = atoi(argv[6]);
    GA.randomPopulationRate = atof(argv[7]);
    GA.ImmigrantRateFromBOA = atof(argv[8]);
    DE.Pn = atof(argv[9]);
    algoType = atoi(argv[10]);
    CM.numOfSamples = atoi(argv[11]);
    mkpfile=atoi(argv[12]);
    DE.noiseType=atoi(argv[13]);
    DE.problemType=atoi(argv[14]);
    DE.environmentType = atoi(argv[15]);
    DE.period=atoi(argv[16]);
    DE.severity=atof(argv[17]);

    printf("\nRunning... Problem type: %d...",DE.problemType);
    fflush(stdout);
    for(int i=1; i<=loop; i++)
    {
        myAlgorithm(i,DE.problemType,algoType,mkpfile);
    }
    cout<<"Done!"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the above code, I want output to first prints the `printf()` part which doesn't have newline thing, and then prints the `cout` part:

```
Running bla bla bla... Done!
```

It runs correctly if I run only one test case, however when I use shell script to run more than one test cases in parallel, it becomes like this:

```
    Running... Problem type: 1...Running... Problem type: 1...
Running... Problem type: 1...
Running... Problem type: 1...
Running... Problem type: 1...
Running... Problem type: 1...
Running... Problem type: 1...
Running... Problem type: 1...
Running... Problem type: 2...
Running... Problem type: 2...
Running... Problem type: 2...
Running... Problem type: 2...Done!
Done!
Done!

Running... Problem type: 2...
Running... Problem type: 2...
Running... Problem type: 3...
Running... Problem type: 3...
Running... Problem type: 3...
Running... Problem type: 3...
Running... Problem type: 2...
Running... Problem type: 3...
Running... Problem type: 3...

Running... Problem type: 2...Running... Problem type: 3...
Running... Problem type: 3...Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
Done!
```

Is there way to make that happen properly? I am asking this here since I think it is an Ubuntu-related problem.

Comment: This question might be better suited for stack overflow (?) that being said (I am sure someone will correct me if I am wrong, as I am far from an expert...) but are you sure you want to be flushing to stdout after `printf(Running...)`? IIRC flushing immediately prints to `stdout` or wherever you're printing, so you print immediately then when another instance runs in parallel you print that instantly without waiting for the previous instance to finish the loop

Comment: This is expected behaviour. Each process running in the background (or in parallel as you write) output when the code says to do. If you remove the ampersands from the script, the `./run` processes will run one at the time, and the output will be in correct order.

Comment: @j-money OP asks how to get proper output order when running shell commands, that’s not a good fit for SO I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meet [GNU `parallel` [image: Install parallel]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/parallel) (`sudo apt install parallel`):

> GNU parallel is a shell tool for executing jobs in parallel using one
>   or more computers. (…) [It] makes sure output from the commands is the
>   same output as you would get had you run the commands sequentially.
>   ([`man parallel`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/parallel.1.html))

In your case with repeating arguments you can make use of [`bash` Brace Expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace) to easily build the command lines. The basic syntax is `parallel COMMAND {} ::: ARGUMENTS`, if you want to give each run multiple arguments take care of [proper quoting](https://askubuntu.com/a/984802/507051) to prevent word splitting, e.g.:

```
$ parallel echo ./run some args {} ::: {"1 0 "{10,25},"2 0 10"}\ {0.{1,2,5},1}
./run some args 1 0 10 0.1
./run some args 1 0 10 0.2
./run some args 1 0 10 0.5
./run some args 1 0 10 1
./run some args 1 0 25 0.1
./run some args 1 0 25 0.2
./run some args 1 0 25 0.5
./run some args 1 0 25 1
./run some args 2 0 10 0.1
./run some args 2 0 10 0.2
./run some args 2 0 10 0.5
./run some args 2 0 10 1
```

Comment: Hey @dessert I hope you are there. When I run this command, it says "insufficient parameters" (see the code above). `parallel  ./run 4 50 5000 100 100 1 5 0 0 0.05 1 101 6 2 {} ::: {1,2,3,4}\ {0,1,2}\ {10,25}\ {0.{1,2,5},1}`. I think it doesn't take the arguments. What should I do?

Comment: @WhoCares it’s hard to say what you need here, but generally add an `echo` as in my answer to see the expansion’s results and be able to track the issue down. You find me in the [general chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Answer (score 2):

Your script output won’t get mixed together if you [redirect the output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file) of each command to a different file. For example:

```
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 0.1 > run-0.1.log &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 0.2 > run-0.2.log &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 0.5 > run-0.5.log &
./run 50 5000 100 100 1.0 2 0.3 0.3 0.05 1 101 0 2 1 0 10 1 > run-1.0.log &
```

You can later open these files and check the details of each process.

Or, if you are not interested in seeing the outputs at all, redirect them to [`/dev/null`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device).