# how to enable cpu parallelism on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cpu, cpu-load

I have a question about multicore cpus

I have a multicore cpu on ubuntu 18.04 OS
How can I get a good performance on heavy process?
I think about cpu parallelism... is this make work every core at very near to full?
[cpu load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtq7D.png)
is that right?
is that able?
How can I make able the cpu parallelism?
Regards !!!

Comment: Not all applications support multi thread  processing, and not all support it well. Try some video encoding with H.264 and you will see all cores utilised for example...

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120040/how-to-run-commands-in-the-shell-in-parallel-without-disrupting-the-output