# How can I print file sizes recursively, reporting permission errors?

Tags: permissions, scripts, files, directory

I have to make a script which prints the sizes of all `.conf` files from `/etc` recursively in a specified file, and that prints the errors caused by the lack of permission in another file. I don't know how to make it. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Wrong website to ask this. We are not a coding service nor is coding a focus of askubuntu. "I need to make a script" eh. What you ask reads more like a one-liner with redirects to  a file.

Comment: What is the "memory" of a conf file? Do you mean the file size?

Comment: I was thinking the same but why would that result in permissions errors :D

Comment: sorry. it was a mistake. i meant the size. and yes, i was referring to a oneliner

Comment: "all files recursively" -- use `find`. find's `-printf` directive can print the file name, size and permissions.

Comment: @Rinzwind We do answer easy student homework questions here frequently. If a consultant charging for services ask a complicated question (requiring many hours of work) in that case I don't answer.

Comment: **Closer Voters:** The question is not off-topic because it involves `find` and `printf` command which is common in **Ask Ubuntu**. Nor can this be considered **Too Broad** nor **Unclear** IMHO.

Comment: @user68186 The version of Linux Kernel, or the version of Ubuntu really doesn't effect answers here. Did you vote question as unclear as a consequence?

Comment: @glennjackman In this context I would interpret "memory" as "Non-Volatile Memory" aka "Non-Volatile Storage" so the size on disk as you accurately suggested. Most people associate "memory" with RAM (**R**andom **A**ccess **M**emory) but technically it applies to ROM, HDD and SSD as well. If you voted **Unclear** will you now retract the vote?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix not when asking for scripts though. Help with one-liners where someone gets stuck sure But -this- shows zero effort.

Comment: @Rinzwind I agree with you on effort. But I recall my college days when IBM PC's were first invented and that BASIC instructor was so useless (perhaps because of his mainframe background) us students were pretty much left teaching each other. I have to give OP benefit of doubt their plight was similar to ours.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I agree the version of Ubuntu should not matter. However, if the OP is running an old EOL version or a non-Ubuntu distro, the question would be off-topic. If OP tells us she is not running Ubuntu or running an EOL version, I will vote to close on that basis.

Comment: @user68186 Please don't refer to OP as "she". Some might construe this comment as stating females have more problems with technology than males. Kindly use the phrase "they" instead of "she". Thank you. Also even if OP was running Linux Mint I would still answer the question because it applies to all Ubuntu versions too. Including Ubuntu version EOL.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I am with Rinzwind. I answer script questions if I know how. However, OP at least has to show some effort in the form of the non-working script (one liner in this case) in the question. If not I will be happy to vote to close on the basis of Mint or EOL version. BTW, I used "she" to break the stereotype that all computer script users are male. I agree with you a gender neutral pronoun is more appropriate. Next time I will use they.

Comment: @Student1234 Please clarify: Which operating system and version do you use? Which permission errors are you referring to? Do you need the individual sizes or the total size of these files? What have you tried, and where did it fail?

Comment: hi. i use ubuntu 18.04 lts. The errors are caused by the lack of permission because i am not allowed to use the terminal as root. I tryed it and i couldn't find ta way to get the files that printed errors separated from the files that don't. Thank you all for your help. All the things helped me. I think it is ok now.

Comment: Please add new information directly to your question ([edit]), *do not* use comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-fprintf` to write output from `find` to a file.

```bsh
$ find /etc -type f,l -name '*.conf' \
    -fprintf ~/filelist '%s %p\n' 2> ~/error.log
```

find options:

- `-type f,l` Search for regular files and symbolic link.
- `-name` Match the base of the file name with shell match pattern.
- `-fprintf` Like *-printf* but writes output to a file instead.

fprintf format:

- `%s` File's size in bytes.
- `%p` File's name (with starting-point included).
- `\n` Newline.

Bash:

- `[n]>file` Redirect file descriptor [n] to "file".
- `~` Expands to the value of the shell parameter HOME.
- `\` Breaks a up long lines into multiple lines.

Comment: Personally I think answer is better without  **`-L`** because it is doubling up on size of `/etc/*.conf` files and becomes misleading IMO. I've shown the differences between your answer and my own below.

Comment: OP seems interested in permissions too. Might want to add `%m` or `%M`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment `find` and `printf` are your friends on this homework assignment. For a one-liner use:

```
find /etc -name "*.conf" -printf "%s %p\n" 1>namesize.txt 2>errors.txt
```

To test the components with output to your screen try out the examples below.

```
$ find /etc -name "*.conf" 1>/dev/null
find: ‘/etc/ssmtp’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/polkit-1/localauthority’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/cups/ssl’: Permission denied
find: ‘/etc/ssl/private’: Permission denied
```

This is the short one that shows permission denied. Regular output is redirected to `/dev/null` (nowhere) so you get to see only the error messges.

```
$ find /etc -name "*.conf" -printf "%s %p\n" 2>/dev/null | column -t
3874   /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
258    /etc/bluetooth/proximity.conf
397    /etc/bluetooth/input.conf
  (... SNIP ...)
1366   /etc/at-spi2/accessibility.conf
13592  /etc/openal/alsoft.conf
1800   /etc/cracklib/cracklib.conf
```

This shows the the list of filenamnes and sizes which is too long to print entirely. The four error messages for "Permission denied" are filtered out with `2>/dev/null` redirecting all errors to "nowhere".

Output is piped (using `|`) to the `column -t` command which pads spaces behind the file sizes in order for the filenames to align in the output.

---

### Compare links to [other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1189508/307523)

The other answer shows links like this:

```
$ find -L /etc -type f -name '*.conf' -fprintf ~/filelist '%s %p\n' 2> ~/error.log
$ grep 45-latin.conf ~/filelist | column -t
4621  /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf
4621  /etc/fonts/conf.avail/45-latin.conf
```

The size of the link inherits the size of the file it points to.

My answer shows links like this:

```
$ find /etc -name "*.conf" -printf "%s %p\n" 1>namesize.txt 2>errors.txt
$ grep 45-latin.conf namesize.txt | column -t
27    /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf
4621  /etc/fonts/conf.avail/45-latin.conf
```

The size of the link is the real size of the link (27 bytes).

So it's a question of how your professor/TA/teacher wishes to links reported in the answer. The homework/Lab assignment should have been more specific on how to handle such intricacies of Linux.

To look at the link use:

```
$ ll /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Aug  2  2018 /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf -> ../conf.avail/45-latin.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bash`’s `globstar` option:

> If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories
>   and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only
>   directories and subdirectories match.

Set it with:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

After that you can match any `.conf` file under `/etc` with `/etc/{,**/}*.conf`, so now a simple `stat` call is enough to solve the task, e. g. for size and filename separated by space:

```
stat -c '%s %N' /etc/{,**/}*.conf
```

To redirect the output of that, use `>file` for stdout and `2>file` for stderr, e. g.:

```
stat -c '%s %N' /etc/{,**/}*.conf >~/stdout 2>~/stderr
```

As the glob doesn’t match any directory for which you don’t have the proper permissions you normally don’t get any permission errors though, but those files are just skipped instead. To list them you can use `find` and search for matching files *not* matching the `o+r` permission, i. e. not readable by others:

```
sudo find /etc -type f -name '*.conf' ! -perm -o+r
```

#### Further reading

- [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237/507051)

Comment: I was thinking a student wouldn't have `sudo` powers but I haven't been in a School's Linux Computer Lab so could not say.

Comment: it was my bad.. missed globstar...

Comment: You can't use "sudo" as per question: "and that prints the errors caused by the lack of permission in another file. "

Comment: @Rinzwind the question is very unclear in this regard, my `stat` approach does what OP asks for without throwing any permission errors – see last paragraph

Comment: @Rinzwind I doubt there is actually a way to show permission errors for files in directories you’re not allowed to read – note that the errors `find` reports **do not** refer to the conf files, but to directories `find` can’t access in general, which is not what OP asked for either. Take `/etc/sudoers.d` for example, it shows up although irrelevant.