# How to view and manage large data in terminal?

Tags: command-line, kernel, text, metadata

How do I manage huge terminal outputs and data to view and analyze it all? For example when I am trying to look at the kernel with ls -lR it will output so much data that it will take me a year just to scroll through all of it and not get anywhere.

When I zoom out of the terminal I see impressive data structures, but the text is too small to read or analyze.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

this might help

[How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file#731237)

it won't make it structured but a good text editor clould make it nicer to read.
also the extra functionality of appending etc can be useful