# How do I save to a file and simultaneously view terminal output?

Tags: command-line

Linked to this question: [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file?newreg=778fa9e9a4f54aff94192f05d20e5db2)

I understand that I can form an output file by using:

```
python3 script.py > output.txt
```

However, I also want to see the output being generated by the python file while it is being saved to output. Is there a simple way to do this on the command line?

Answer (score 2):

Use a `tee` command. It is meant exactly for this.

```
python3 script.py | tee output.txt
```

It can also be done in more complicated way. Run your original command in the background and simultaneusly view the contents of file `output.txt` in the foreground. I sometimes prefer to do it that way, especially for long-running processes, since I can at any time abort viewing of the output file and return to it anytime later:

```
python3 script.py > output.txt &
tail -f output.txt
```

(you can Ctrl-C in the `tail` command at any time, and run again the command later).