# Use "source" within 'script' command

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, anaconda

I want to use the script command to see my output both in the command line and also store it at the same time, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1198795/471426).

Now, I can do in my command line:

```
script
source activate foo
python my_file.py
exit
```

Quite a hassle if I have to do this often, so I thought I would write a bash script that automatizes this. I tried to literally paste these commands into a command line file, but it would wait for input after `script`.

Instead, here's how I thought of implementing this in a bash script (such that I would just run the script and it would do it all:

```
#!/bin/bash
script ../output.txt -c ' /home/foo/anaconda3/condabin/conda activate myenv3 && python myfile.py'
```

And this gives me a `CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to use 'conda activate'.`

Why am I not using directly "source activate foo" or ". activate foo" as I would usually do? Well, if I try that, I get `bash: activate: No such file or directory`

I understand that `/bin/bash` apparently is not configured to do this in Ubuntu -- what should be my way forward?

Comment: I'm just guessing here...but in order to use `conda`, there are variables that have to be set in your `~/.bashrc` (should be near the end of the file?).  So, you need to `source` that first, before you run `conda`.  When you start a new `bash` shell, it runs it for you.

Comment: Why can't you just the commands you know work each time at the terminal in a script?

Comment: @vanadium I tried to copy&paste my commands into the bash script but it would just execute the first command ("script") and wait for further input.

Comment: @Ray Indeed, there are lines at the end of `~/.bashrc` that include anaconda paths. So youre suggesting adding ". ~/.bashrc &&" at the beginning of the `-c ' /home/....` sequence? Because I tried that and it didn't change the outpu

Comment: I know you need to source something, but how that fits into the `script` command that you're running is something that perhaps someone else can fill in for you -- I've never done that myself.  Maybe try this...in your installation, there is a file.  Mine is at:  `/opt/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` (i.e., fill in the beginning for your system).  Try sourcing this instead of `.~/bashrc` first?

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that `script -c` invokes a *noninterative* shell? At least if your `~/.bashrc` is based on the default Ubuntu one, it will bail almost immediately when it detects that (*"# If not running interactively, don't do anything"*)

Answer (score 0):

When you run commands with `script -c`, they are run in a *noninteractive* shell:

```
$ script ../output.txt -c 'echo "\$0 = $0 ; FLAGS = $-"'
Script started, file is ../output.txt
$0 = bash ; FLAGS = hBc
Script done, file is ../output.txt
```

The flags are different from the normal interactive shell (note the presence of the `i` flag):

```
$ echo "\$0 = $0 ; FLAGS = $-"
$0 = -bash ; FLAGS = himBHs
```

Although noninteractive, non-login shells read your `~/.bashrc`, they likely processes it differently. In particular, the default `~/.bashrc` that would have been copied from `/etc/skel` when your account was created starts with:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

meaning that any conda related content that you added at the end of your `~/.bashrc` will not get executed (and sourcing `~/.bashrc` again won't help).

I don't know much about conda, but assuming it is capable of being run in such a shell, then one possible workaround would be the following:

- remove the conda related portion of your `~/.bashrc` to a separate file
- source that file from your `~/.bashrc` to keep the existing behavior for your interactive shell
- source that file (instead of `~/.bashrc`) first in your `script -c ' ... '` command

Comment: Fourth option: move the conda-related part from the end of `~/.bashrc` to the beginning, before the part that you quoted which returns for non-interactive shell.

Comment: @raj indeed - although of course that may change the behavior of non-interactive shells in other contexts, which may be undesirable