# Outputting gpustats to a file

Tags: gpu, monitoring

If I want to have gpu stats I can use gpustats as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51406093/4451521)

Is there a way to output this results (with watch) to a file?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save terminal output to a file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420981/how-do-i-save-terminal-output-to-a-file)

Answer (score -1):

Got this using

```
gpustat -cp --watch 2>&1 | tee ResultFile.txt
```